# A super basic udev rule that worked in the past doesnt run anymore

Tags: udev

I have got this rule at `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-test.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", RUN+="touch /tmp/test"
```

It used to trigger stuff in RUN, now it does nothing anymore, it doesn't even create this file when I plug in a USB mouse. In a forum it was suggested to create a file in order to test if it runs at all.

```
cat /tmp/test
cat: /tmp/test: No such file or directory
```

What can I do? I have tried

```
sudo udevadm control --log-priority=debug
journalctl -f
```

but it doesn't print anything at all about my rule

Comment: After multiple reboots and `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules` it starts showing `event5: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-test.rules:1 RUN 'touch /tmp/test/c'`. ffs is this annoying

Answer (score 0):

yeah, it just randomly works now. Good luck with your own rules.

Maybe try `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`

touching files didn't work by the way, `journalctl -f` says `touch` exits with code 1, even when touching in a folder with permissive rights.